# microservices versioning with header

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

issue is when i am looking swagger for **v1** there i can see one endpoint which is valid, but for **v2** i have given two endpoints inside controller, but `/allusers` endpoint i am not able to see. below are the controller.

**controller v1:**

```
package com.springboot.rest.controller.v1;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.springboot.rest.dto.UserDto;
import com.springboot.rest.service.UserService;

@RestController(value = "userControllerV1")
@RequestMapping(value = "/userinfo", produces = "application/json")
public class UserController {

    public static final String X_ACCEPT_VERSION_V1 = "X-Accept-Version" + "=" + "v1";
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/allusers", headers = X_ACCEPT_VERSION_V1)
    public List<UserDto> getUserinfo() {
        List<UserDto> finalResults = userService.getAllUserInfo();
        return finalResults;
    }
}
```

**controller v2:**

```
package com.springboot.rest.controller.v2;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.springboot.rest.dto.UserDto;
import com.springboot.rest.service.UserService;

@RestController(value = "userControllerV2")
@RequestMapping(value = "/userinfo", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class UserController {
    
    public static final String X_ACCEPT_VERSION_V2 = "X-Accept-Version" + "=" + "v2";

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/allusers", headers = X_ACCEPT_VERSION_V2)
    public List<UserDto> getUserinfo() {
        List<UserDto> finalResults = userService.getAllUserInfo();
        return finalResults;
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/message", headers = X_ACCEPT_VERSION_V2)
    public String greetMessage() {
        return userService.getGreetMessage();
        
    }
}
```

and i don't want to change my `getUserinfo()` method, could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

URI paths for <kbd>/allusers</kbd> end point are same in both the controllers where as api endpoints should be unique through out the application.  You can add version in the uri which will make it unique. For eg.

> @RequestMapping(value = "/**v2**/userinfo", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this will change my mapping for both v1 and v2, that is not useful. any other ways please.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to map two endpoints with same URI. But there is a practice to put your version into custom headers and parse it in a filter so that URI endpionts will never be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. i achieve this with OpenApi. below link is having the solution.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4FwdCgik5M

Answer (score 0):

I did many ways, but finally OpenApi and adding filter did it for me. below is the OpenApiConfig file and link for those who wants to achieve this.

```
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenApi() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .components(new Components())
                .info(new Info().title("User-Management Microservice")
                .description("demo-microservice for user-management")
                .termsOfService("www.abc.com")
                .contact(new io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Contact()
                .email("abc.com")
                .name("user-management"))
                .version("1.0"));
    }
    
    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi v1OpenApi() {
        String[] packagesToScan = {"com.springboot.rest.controller.v1"};
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder().setGroup("v1 version").packagesToScan(packagesToScan).build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi v2OpenApi() {
        String[] packagesToScan = {"com.springboot.rest.controller.v2"};
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder().setGroup("v2 version").packagesToScan(packagesToScan).build();
    }

}
```

use below link for step by step explanation:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4FwdCgik5M